# django_tables2 conflict multiple table on same page

Tags: django, django-tables2

Using django_tables2, when two tables are used on a page, there will be a conflict and only one table will be ordered correctly is there a solution ?

```
class Table_class1(tables.Table):
  uuid = tables.Column()
  name1 = tables.Column()

  class Meta:
    pass   

class Table_class2(tables.Table):
  uuid = tables.Column()
  name2 = tables.Column()

  class Meta: 
        pass

staticmethod 
 def set_table(request, table_class1, table_lines):
   table1 = table_class1(table_lines, prefix="1-")
   RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
   return table        
                                                                                                                                                   staticmethod 
def set_table(request, table_class2, table_lines):
   table2 = table_class2(table_lines, prefix="2-")
   RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
   return table
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#querystring-fields) you can add a prefix to each table

Comment: I just do what the documentaion say but conflict still there.

Comment: table1 = table_class1(table_lines1, prefix="1-") and               table2 = table_class2(table_lines2, prefix="2-")

Comment: how are you building your sorting querystrings? Coudl you share some code please, Views, Tables, templates

Comment: Could you update your question with the code so that it is readable and everyone will see it, thanks

Comment: Could you update your _answer_ with both a [proper link to the right place](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/query-string-fields.html?highlight=prefix) and a code example so I don't need to have gone scouring the docs?